# HTML and Android don't work together

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax

Here is what I am trying do:

1. Save sensor info from Android tablet to txt file online
2. Open a webpage to read that data continuously using ajax calls

Note: Website and Android app are running simultaneously

Android part:

```
   try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://.../save.php");                            
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            //Could do something better with response.
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error1:  " + e.toString());
    }
```

JS part

```
 setInterval("DisplayBall()", 500);
 function DisplayBall()
 {
var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("TotalTime").value = 0;
        //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        AssignResult(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}   
//xmlHttp.open("GET", "TINBCoordinates.txt", true); 
//xmlHttp.send();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "read.php", true); 
xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Why do these two interfere & make my program unresponsive?

Comment: What do u mean? Its not clear.... does your android app interfere wit your website??

Comment: What about using a webdebugger... putting logs and watching the console... etc. You should at least be capable to know if the problem is in the Android or in the web app...!

Comment: out of curiosity, what version of Android is this, and if it's 3.0 or higher do you have your HTTP call in a separate thread (as is required)?

Comment: Yes, I run in a separate thread. It writes data in the file, but my webpage doesn't get it and crashes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using PhoneGap.js it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: seems like PhoneGap interacts with the device that it's executing on. Sorry if my explanation was ambiguos but my js and html run on a laptop whereas Android code runs on a tablet. Thank you